# Sockets Help and Advice

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn how to use Sockets to make web requests, but I'm struggling to find anything online. I've found lots of "client" -> "server" tutorials using sockets, but nothing that talks about making web requests, scrapers, etc.

I want to be able to develop multi threaded apps using sockets as I've heard they are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to learn how to use Sockets to make web requests, but I'm struggling to find anything online.

If by *web requests* you mean HTTP requests then using sockets would be too low level. I would recommend you using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for this purpose. For example here's how to send an HTTP request to google.com and fetch the resulting HTML:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's an example for learning using sockets:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new TcpClient("www.google.com", 80))
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(
@"GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Connection: close

");
            writer.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: absolutely never write any code like this in any real application.

Comment: I understand that Darin, but I'm still willing to learn. I like a challenge. WebClient is missing important things when setting headers too.

Comment: @Peppi Hasting, it's not missing anything. Have you looked at the [`Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) property? As it name implies it allows you to set HTTP headers along with your request.

Comment: Yes Darin. I already use HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse. I am wanting to learn how to use Sockets for the same thing.

Comment: @Peppi Hasting, sockets are low level TCP. You really don't want to reinvent wheels here.

Comment: Darin, I appreciate your concern. My need to learn is purely to deepen my knowledge.

Comment: @Peppi Hasting, OK, I see that you insist. See my update. But honestly if you want to deepen your knowledge I would recommend you reading the HTTP protocol specification. As I said using sockets for doing HTTP is like trying to kill a fly with a nuclear bomb.

Comment: @Peppi Hasting, you are welcome. If my post was helpful to you consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.